# Transforming to polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I want to transform from planar $x,y$ coordinates to $r,\theta$ coordinates, where

$$r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2},\quad \theta = \arctan(y/x)$$
$$x = r\cos\theta, \quad y = r\sin\theta.$$

To do this I wish to compute the Jacobian matrix. One first step is computing $\partial r/\partial x$. I find

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right)^{-1} = \left(\frac{\partial{(r \cos\theta)}}{\partial r}\right)^{-1} = \frac{1}{\cos\theta}.$$

However I also find

$$\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \sqrt{x^2+y^2} = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} = \frac{r\cos\theta}{r} = \cos \theta.$$

Why do I get these contradictory results?

Comment: $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x} = (\frac{\partial x}{\partial r})^{-1}$ isn't valid

Comment: The reason that $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\ne (\frac{\partial x}{\partial r})^{-1}$ is that the conditions of the inverse function theorem do not apply to partial derivatives.  The multivariable inverse function theorem says that the *total* derivative of an inverse function is the inverse of the total derivative of the function.  You can verify for yourself that this in fact does hold for the polar transform by calculating the Jacobian of the transform and its inverse.

Comment: I see, so it's a statement about the matrix I am trying to compute, not the individual entries. Thank you!

Comment: [I think you mean](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) $\theta=\operatorname{atan2}(y,\,x)$.

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments you cannot just "reverse" the partial derivative like this.

Instead you can actually calculate $\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ by considering also derivating $\theta$ respectively to $x$ (while $y$ is fixed).

$\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}=\dfrac{-y}{x^2\left(1+\dfrac{y^2}{x^2}\right)}=\dfrac{-y}{x^2+y^2}=\dfrac{-\sin \theta}{r}$

$\begin{align}\dfrac{\partial r}{\partial x}
&=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(\dfrac{x}{\cos \theta}\right)
=\dfrac 1{\cos \theta}+x\dfrac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\left(\dfrac 1{\cos \theta}\right)\dfrac{\partial \theta}{\partial x}
=\dfrac 1{\cos \theta}+x\left(\dfrac{\sin \theta}{\cos^2 \theta}\right)\left(\dfrac{-\sin \theta}{r}\right)\\\\
&=\dfrac 1{\cos \theta}+x\left(\dfrac{-\sin^2 \theta}{x\cos \theta}\right)
=\dfrac{1-\sin^2 \theta}{\cos \theta}=\cos \theta
\end{align}$

Now both results agree.

*Yet you can notice that you still needed to express $\theta$ in term of $x,y$ to get its proper derivative. Thus what you somehow tried to avoid for $r$ you have to do for $\theta$, so it was preferable to go for your second calculation right away.*

Answer (score 1):

Your strategy failed because you conflated partial derivatives that hold different things constant. Often, what's held constant is shown as a subscript outside brackets. In particular, $\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)_\theta=\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right)_\theta^{-1}=\sec\theta$ but $\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)_y=\frac{x}{r}$. So strictly speaking, the Jacobian should be written as$$\frac{dxdy}{drd\theta}=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial r}\right)_{\theta} & \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial\theta}\right)_{r}\\
\left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial r}\right)_{\theta} & \left(\frac{\partial y}{\partial\theta}\right)_{r}
\end{array}\right|=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\cos\theta & -r\sin\theta\\
\sin\theta & r\cos\theta
\end{array}\right|=r,$$or in the other direction$$\frac{drd\theta}{dxdy}=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}\right)_{y} & \left(\frac{\partial r}{\partial y}\right)_{x}\\
\left(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial x}\right)_{y} & \left(\frac{\partial\theta}{\partial y}\right)_{x}
\end{array}\right|=\left|\begin{array}{cc}
\frac{x}{r} & \frac{y}{r}\\
-\frac{y}{r^{2}} & \frac{x}{r^{2}}
\end{array}\right|=\frac{1}{r}.$$